# I am not able to connect to internet using my Micromax MMX 353G USB 3G Modem in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: internet-connection, usb-modem

I am recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in my Acer Aspire 5542 laptop. I am not able to connect to internet using my Micromax MMX 353G USB 3G Modem ( I'm using Vodafone Mobile as ISP with APN "www" for 2G Network). I don't know how to configure my modem to connect to internet. But i can easily do that using Windows 7. Pls kindly help. Is there in GUI application to do it as i m not well versed with the terminal codes.

Answer (score 1):

irst open network connection from your dash(hit Super key and search for network connection). Then go to Mobile Broadband tab.

[image]

click `add`.

[image]

select device and hit `forward`

[image]

choose country and hit `forward`

[image]

choose provider and hit `forward`

[image]

choose your plan. if not listed select other and give access point name.

[image]

hit `apply`. you have created mobile broadband connection.
if you want to edit then open `network connections` from dash.
to connect it . click button between bluetooth and sound on top panel. then click name of just created Mobile broadband network.

guide is described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/connecting-mobile.html)

Comment: thanx i have somehow made it to detect by using this command:- sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x9605. now it shows in the network applet if i go to it through dash but it doesnot show when click the network icon in the top panel. for it to show i again have to type the code in the terminal and wait for sometime.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download a script called `sakis3g`
2. Place it in your home folder
3. Type `sudo chmod +x sakis3g` in terminal
4. Wait for 1 minute and you would get your connection name in top bar.

Note: I have been looking for a solution to this problem the whole of the past year, this one is the best I've found, even though sometimes it doesn't work, most of the time it does.